# Unwanted whitespace between an <img> and an adjacent <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little bit weird problem with my HTML. I never had this problem before.

test page: http://jsfiddle.net/egjJ5/1/

I see white space between the image and the black div. When I take out DTD, it renders fine.

Do i have a problem with my html or css?

Comment: It might not be a bad time to switch to the HTML5 doctype anyhow, even if that doesn't solve your question.  http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image is an `inline-block` and the div underneath it is a `block`.  There are several ways you could fix this.  One would be to add `display: block` to the image as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/egjJ5/12/).

Comment: Correction: Images have an `inline-block` behavior.  But the solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your img element a block element:

```
display: block;
```